# Can I fail asp.net visual studio 2013 project builds if there's syntax errors in javascript files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Sometimes I have syntax errors underlined in my .js files in my Asp.net MVC project. I noticed that the project still builds though, and when I build then debug I waste a few valuable seconds navigating to the place that runs that code in order for it to fail (fairly silently at that) in the browser.

Can I tell visual studio to fail the build if it detects an error in my javascript syntax?

If not, is there a command line tool out there that can detect javascript syntax errors? If so, I can call it post-build.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to use a pre-build event in VS alongside JSLint which is a JS code quality tool. Not tried it myself but might be possible with it.

Answer (score 2):

There's JSLint.NET. It's a .NET wrapper around JSLint and there is a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSLintNet.MSBuild/) which installs an MSBuild target into your project for JS validation:

https://jslintnet.codeplex.com/

Install the package into your MVC project using:

```
PM> Install-Package JSLintNet.MSBuild
```

I just tried it and it works nicely. You'll want to set up a `JSLintNet.json` [settings file](https://jslintnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=JSLint.NET%20Settings&referringTitle=Documentation) in your project to ignore third party js libraries like jQuery and Bootstrap e.g.

```
{
   "ignore": [
      "\\Scripts\\Libraries\\"
   ] 
}
```

Comment: I'll look into this sometime soon. Thank you very much. Could I then use MSBuild (plus library files) on a machine without visual studio and have builds fail there too?

Comment: Yes. Taking it a step further you could write a script for your build that invokes nuget.exe, restores the `JSLintNet.MSBuild` package, and then starts the build.